# boostrap классы в css?

Tags: css, bootstrap

здесь указаны стили прямо в коде
https://itchief.ru/examples/lab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=b4-sticky-top

```
<div style="height: 3000px; background-color: #fefefe; border-radius: 4px; color: #818182; padding-top: 30px; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;">
```

Если есть `div class="col-6">`
То в css написать что-то типа

```
.col-6
{
ширина у "col-6";//.col-6 {width: 50%;}
}
```

Но выше написанное делает то чтобы не было прописано вот так:

```
div class="col-6" style="width: 50%;">
```

Как добиться такой результат ?

Comment: из js генерируется скорее всего

Comment: elem.cssText = "здесь пишешь что надо" и в итоге вот такая штукенция будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы можете добавить дополнительный класс внутри класса ниже приведено пример

```css
.my-class{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 my-class border"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```